# AES-ECB attack encryption audio fie

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher, ecb

I got two audio files one is encrypted and the other file is a part of the plaintext. I want to extract all the plaintext. I am using the AES-ECB mode, the size of the block is 128 bits and the start of the extracted plaintext is not aligned with the start of the cipher text.
So I need to align these two audio files. I don't know how to do that and how that would help me to extract all the plaintext.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.se What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: it is a homework . I need to write a python code to solve it.I wasn't able to figure out the idea. I understand the weakness of AES-ECB mode but I don't know how can i exploit that in this problem.

Comment: **A small hint as per our policy:** One possible way is to find two ciphertext blocks that are the same and at the same time, you had the same in the plaintexts.

Comment: okay thank you for the hint. I will try to work on that.

Comment: Keeping in consideration that my two audio files are not aligned, i tried to search for the repetaed blocks in the encrypted file and in the plaintext file. I extracted the pattern for each block; how many each block is repeated and in what indexes. I tried to make a match but i didn't find any. Could you tell me if i am in the right path or i should look for another alternative?

Comment: You seem on the right path because at least two same ciphertexts are needed to align and the same spaced plaintext is required. I was expecting something like this; you match the plaintext with ciphertext at some point then the rest blocks will be in the matching part so that one can solve. So, I was expecting more pairs to solve. Don't expect to break AES.